# Session is not created during login using asp.net application after Visual Studio Build and Run

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

When I Debug and Run my Web application in Visual Studio, it displays me the login page. But, when I login, it again redirects me to the Login page. When I Debug I found that Session is not being set. Although I have written the Code for Session Set.

```
protected void PerformLogin()
{
    int page = 0;
    string PageName = "";
    try
    {
        string MstTable = obj.FindMstTable(txtloginid.Text, ddluser.SelectedValue);
        string query = @"select EMAI_PRMY,CATEGORY_CD,SUB_CATEGORY_CD,PASSWORD,UNIQUE_ID,ACCOUNT_STATUS
        from " + MstTable + " where EMAI_PRMY= @Email and PASSWORD= @Password";

        SqlCommand sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn);
        sqlcommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlcommand.CommandText = query;
        sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtloginid.Text);
        sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtpass.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcommand);
        da.Fill(ds);


        Session["UserEmail"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EMAI_PRMY"].ToString();
        Session["UserCategory"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CATEGORY_CD"].ToString();
        Session["UserSbcat"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["SUB_CATEGORY_CD"].ToString();

        Session["uniqueid"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UNIQUE_ID"].ToString();

        Session["schl"] = "dbconstr";

        // ** THIS CODE IS EXECUTED SUCCESSFULLY WHILE DEBUGGING
        ** BUT WHEN YOU SEE THE VALUE OF SESSION VARIABLE IN IMMEDIATE WINDOW
        ** IT WILL NOT SHOW YOU THE VALUE AS IT WAS NOT SET.
        **//

        string CCR_ID = MethodObj.CheckCCR_ID_Func(Convert.ToString(Session["uniqueid"]));
        if (CCR_ID != "")
        Response.Redirect("Consumer/ConsumerL1.aspx");
        else
        Response.Redirect("Consumer/ConsumerL0.aspx");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblmsg.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}

protected void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        PerformLogin();
    }
}
```

Comment: try to debug your code and check whether your `DataSet -> ds` have some value in it.

Comment: Yes, It have values in that and that too are correct values.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have used abandon in the login Page as below. Try to remove and debug

```
Session.Abandon();
```

Comment: No, I have searched Entire Solution. Session.Abandon is not there.

Answer (score 0):

please check your web.config

And also check

```
Session.Abandon()
```

if you use in your page

Comment: Yes, I have checked that. It didn't helped. 

Also, One more thing I would like to mention that, when you try to login after 3-4 Hrs of idle time after project build, session objects are created and it login successfully.